# How to reshape to long format, removing NAs cells?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a table with social researchers and revisiters in places that didn't get service on the first try, I need to reshape my dataframe to long format without whitespace or NAs, that seemed easy to me, but I'm not getting success in my attempts.

```
  zone situation Researcher1 Researcher2 Researcher3 Researcher4 revisit1 revisit2 revisit3
1    3  Answered          NA          NA           4          NA       NA       10       NA
2    3   Refusal          NA          NA          15          NA       NA        5       NA
3    1  Answered          10          NA          NA          NA        2       NA       NA
4    1   Refusal           7          NA          NA          NA        5       NA       NA
5    2  Answered          NA          15          NA          NA        3       NA       NA
6    2   Refusal          NA           3          NA          NA        0       NA       NA
7    4  Answered          NA          NA          NA          13       NA       NA        4
8    4   Refusal          NA          NA          NA           8       NA       NA        4


long_rsch <- reshape(survey, direction="long", timevar="Situation", 
                     idvar="zone", 
                     varying=list(c("Researcher 1", "Researcher 2", 
                                    "Researcher 3", "Researcher 4"), 
                                  c("revisit 1", "revisit 2", "revisit3")), 
                     v.names=c("first team", "Revisit"))
```

Gives me:

```
Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  : 
  'varying' arguments must be the same length
```

I expected something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(zone = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4), situation = c("Answer", 
"Refusal", "Answer", "Refusal", "Answer", "Refusal", "Answer", 
"Refusal"), `Researcher 1` = c(NA, NA, 10, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `Researcher 2` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 3, NA, NA), `Researcher 3` = c(4, 
    15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Researcher 4` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 13, 8), `revisit 1` = c(NA, NA, 2, 5, 3, 0, NA, 
    NA), `revisit 2` = c(10, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `revisit 3` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("Researcher"), names_to = "Researchers", values_to = "Result 1") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("revisit"), names_to = "revisit", values_to = "Result 2", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(zone)

# A tibble: 8 × 6
   zone situation Researchers  `Result 1` revisit   `Result 2`
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>             <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1     1 Answer    Researcher 1         10 revisit 1          2
2     1 Refusal   Researcher 1          7 revisit 1          5
3     2 Answer    Researcher 2         15 revisit 1          3
4     2 Refusal   Researcher 2          3 revisit 1          0
5     3 Answer    Researcher 3          4 revisit 2         10
6     3 Refusal   Researcher 3         15 revisit 2          5
7     4 Answer    Researcher 4         13 revisit 3          4
8     4 Refusal   Researcher 4          8 revisit 3          4
```

You could also then do a bit more cleaning to get to this:

```
mutate(df, situation = as.factor(situation), 
           Researchers = as.numeric(str_remove(Researchers, "Researcher ")),
              revisit = as.numeric(str_remove(revisit, "revisit ")))

# A tibble: 8 × 6
   zone situation Researchers `Result 1` revisit `Result 2`
  <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 Answer              1         10       1          2
2     1 Refusal             1          7       1          5
3     2 Answer              2         15       1          3
4     2 Refusal             2          3       1          0
5     3 Answer              3          4       2         10
6     3 Refusal             3         15       2          5
7     4 Answer              4         13       3          4
8     4 Refusal             4          8       3          4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day, tidyverse to reshape  is something new for me, it worked perfectly.

Comment: You can use `cols = contains("Researcher")` and `cols = contains("revisit")` in `pivot_longer()` to make it concise. And add `values_drop_na = TRUE` to avoid `filter(...)`.

Comment: Good work but are there any reasons to use `cols = -c(zone, situation, starts_with("revisit"))` instead of just `cols = starts_with("Researcher")` ?

Comment: @user18894435 see Darren's comment

Comment: the explanation is that it's 2 a.m. over here and I'm sleep deprived  i did transcribe the input though!

Answer (score 4):

`reshape` is actually straightforward if you take a second and understand how it works.

```
reshape(survey, direction="long", varying=3:6, sep='', v.names='Result1', timevar='Researcher') |>
  reshape(direction="long", varying=3:5, sep='', idvar=c('id', 'Researcher'), 
          v.names=c('Result2'), timevar='Revisit') |>
  na.omit()
#       zone situation Researcher Result1 id Revisit Result2
# 3.1.1    1  Answered          1      10  3       1       2
# 4.1.1    1   Refusal          1       7  4       1       5
# 5.2.1    2  Answered          2      15  5       1       3
# 6.2.1    2   Refusal          2       3  6       1       0
# 1.3.2    3  Answered          3       4  1       2      10
# 2.3.2    3   Refusal          3      15  2       2       5
# 7.4.3    4  Answered          4      13  7       3       4
# 8.4.3    4   Refusal          4       8  8       3       4
```

*Explanation:*

*zone* can't be used as `idvar` because it's not unique. `reshape` automatically takes care of a unique `idvar` if we don't specify one (and as long there is no variable called `"id"`), the new *id* column will be added in the output.

There are two `reshape`s needed, you get the error because *Researchers* and *revisits* refer to different "times" (else *Researcher1* gets *revisit1*, *Researcher2* gets *revisit2*, etc.), so the first `reshape` is on `Researcher*`; if we specify `varying` as a range of the `Researcher*` columns and use `sep=''` (in contrast to e.g. `sep='.'` which is the default), `reshape` can guess the names correctly, and we don't need to type them.

Correspondingly the second `reshape` is on `revisit*`, but now with *id* and *Researcher* as `idvar`.

Finally, we can omit the unwanted NA lines with a simple `na.omit()`.

---

*Data:*

```
survey <- structure(list(zone = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4), situation = c("Answered", 
"Refusal", "Answered", "Refusal", "Answered", "Refusal", "Answered", 
"Refusal"), Researcher1 = c(NA, NA, 10, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA), Researcher2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 15, 3, NA, NA), Researcher3 = c(4, 15, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Researcher4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13, 8), 
    revisit1 = c(NA, NA, 2, 5, 3, 0, NA, NA), revisit2 = c(10, 
    5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), revisit3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider again base R's `reshape`. Since *Researcher* and *revisit* columns are not related columns, simply `reshape` twice via a generalized method with final `merge`:

```r
id_cols = c("zone", "situation")
researcher_cols <- names(df)[grep("Researcher", names(df))]
revisit_cols <- names(df)[grep("revisit", names(df))]

special_reshape <- function(data, id_cols, focused_cols, drop_cols, var_name, value_name) {
  reshape(
    data,
    idvar = id_cols,
    varying = focused_cols,
    times = focused_cols,
    drop = drop_cols,
    v.names = value_name,
    timevar = var_name,
    new.row.names = 1:1E5,
    direction = "long"
  ) |> subset(
    !is.na(get(value_name))
  )
}

df_long <- merge(
  special_reshape(df, id_cols, researcher_cols, revisit_cols, "researcher", "result 1"), 
  special_reshape(df, id_cols, revisit_cols, researcher_cols, "revisit", "result 2"),
  by = id_cols
)

df_long
#   zone situation   researcher result 1   revisit result 2
# 1    1    Answer Researcher 1       10 revisit 1        2
# 2    1   Refusal Researcher 1        7 revisit 1        5
# 3    2    Answer Researcher 2       15 revisit 1        3
# 4    2   Refusal Researcher 2        3 revisit 1        0
# 5    3    Answer Researcher 3        4 revisit 2       10
# 6    3   Refusal Researcher 3       15 revisit 2        5
# 7    4    Answer Researcher 4       13 revisit 3        4
# 8    4   Refusal Researcher 4        8 revisit 3        4
```